# Tool for HPP testing?

Tags: penetration-test, http

Is there an automated vulnerability scanner that supports HPP (HTTP Parameter Pollution)?

Since all I need is to take a query string and perform basic modifications / add new parameters, I was surprised to not find any. I can make my own in python, but I'm afraid it wouldn't be as effective as any other - if there is one out.

Comment: As tool recommendations are off-topic on this site, this question will likely get closed. It's not personal. See https://security.stackexchange.com/help for more information.

Comment: BTW, the reason you're not finding tools is because HPP is not a common term. Try searching for 'http fuzzer' and you'll find what you need.

Comment: There are lots of well-known HTTP fuzzers, if that's what you are indeed looking for.